# Finding distance between two points by following polyline using R

Tags: shapefile, r, polygon, distance

I have a polyline shapefile that follows the center of a stream, and I have coordinates for animal positions within the stream (not necessarily immediately on the line), and I am trying to calculate the distance between points by going from point1 to the line, following the line to point2, then going from the line to point2 (see illustration below). This should return a single value that (given the width of my stream) is a fairly close approximation to the distance and animal would have to swim to get between two points. I need to be able to do this in R. (note that points are often near the middle of the line, so I need to find the path to go to the nearest point on the line).

In the image below, the blue dotted line is the total path for which I want a distance.

[image]

Comment: I think you illustrated well the problem, but you will have better chance of getting an answer if you post the coordinates of the points you illustrated.

Comment: Is your "polyline" only ever a simple line, with no branches? There's packages for network distance (like on a road network) but that would be overkill for if your stream is only a simple line.

Comment: also: "note that points are often near the middle of the line, so I need to find the path to go to the nearest point on the line" do you mean the path might go to a location on the line that *isnt* a vertex (red dot, in your diagram) of the line?

Comment: Following @Spacedman suggestion, I think you may want to check [sfnetworks](https://github.com/luukvdmeer/sfnetworks) if you are working with complex network object, creating a wrapper around [st_shortest_path](https://luukvdmeer.github.io/sfnetworks/reference/spatial_shortest_paths.html). I can try providing an example if you add some data.

Comment: If its as simple as the diagram, it would be simpler to convert the line to points, work out the point-vertex distances using Pythagoras, then the same for the line segments between the vertexes nearest the data points.

Comment: In response to the questions,

@Spacedman, it is just a simple line, no branches.

Just going to the nearest vertex is fine.

I've come up with a work-around for now that reduces the line to points, but it is rather slow on my large data set, so if someone has a better alternative it would be useful.

I'll check out sfnetworks. thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example that walks through how to do it:

```
require(maptools)
require(sp)
require(rgeos)
require(sf)
require(nngeo)
require(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)


# generate random data and create a line
prep_df <- data.frame(
  x = runif(10, min = 0, max = 100),
  y = runif(10, min = 0, max = 100)
)

prep_df <- prep_df[order(prep_df$x), ]

dummyline <- st_linestring(as.matrix(prep_df))

# pick start and end points arbitrarily
dstart <- st_point(c(20, 60))
dend <- st_point(c(80, 40))

# note, this won't find the shortest path overall,
# just the shortest path to the line
start_on_path <- st_nearest_points(dummyline, dstart)
end_on_path <- st_nearest_points(dummyline, dend)

# break line into line segments
dummysegments <- st_segments(dummyline)

# return all the segments between where the starting and ending path
# are on the dummyline, except first and last, because we're going to chop those up

onramp_segment_index<-st_nearest_feature(st_cast(start_on_path, "POINT")[1], dummysegments)
offramp_segment_index<-st_nearest_feature(st_cast(end_on_path, "POINT")[1], dummysegments)

middlesegments <-
  dummysegments[seq(
    onramp_segment_index + 1,
    offramp_segment_index - 1
  )]
middlesegments <- lapply(
  middlesegments, st_sfc
)

# create line from intersection with line to end of line segment
start_second_leg <-
  st_sfc(
    st_linestring(
      as.matrix(
        rbind(
          start_on_path[[1]][c(1, 3)],
          dummysegments[[
            # get segment where start_on_path intersects
            onramp_segment_index
          ]][c(2, 4)]
        )
      )
    )
  )

# create line from start of segment to intersection with line to end
end_second_leg <-
  st_sfc(
    st_linestring(
      as.matrix(
        rbind(
          end_on_path[[1]][c(1, 3)],
          dummysegments[[
            offramp_segment_index
          ]][c(1, 3)]
        )
      )
    )
  )


# consolidate segments into one object
final_path <-
  st_sfc(
    rbind(
      start_on_path,
      start_second_leg,
      cbind(unlist(middlesegments, recursive = FALSE)),
      end_second_leg,
      end_on_path
    )
  )


# union lines into one line
final_path_single <- final_path[1]

for (i in seq(2, length(final_path))) {
  print(i)
  final_path_single <- st_union(final_path_single, final_path[i])
}


# plot lines to visualize what is going where
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = dummyline, color = "light blue", size = 4) +
  geom_sf(data = dstart) +
  geom_sf(data = dend) +
  geom_sf(data = start_on_path, color = "red", size = 4) +
  geom_sf(data = end_on_path, color = "red", size = 4) +
  geom_sf(data = start_second_leg, color = "yellow", size = 2) +
  geom_sf(data = end_second_leg, color = "yellow", size = 2) +
  geom_sf(data = final_path, color = "purple", size = 0.75) +
  geom_text(
    label = round(st_length(final_path), 1),
    data = data.frame(st_coordinates(st_centroid(final_path))),
    aes(
      x = X,
      y = Y
    )
  )

# total distance
print(paste("distance =", sum(st_length(final_path_single))))

print(paste("length of segments distance =", sum(st_length(final_path))))
```

[image]